# Crystal reports suppression not working on some computers

Tags: vb6, crystal-reports, ms-word

I have a VB6 app that uses Crystal reports 8.5. The report defined in Crystal reports is displayed to the user in Microsoft word. It has a section that is suppressed by using the "suppress" keyword within the report definition. On some computers the resulting word document contains the rows that are supposed to be not shown. The data is present in the fields within the word doc but the font color property is set to white. What is causing this problem and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean 'displayed in word'?

Are you exporting the report to a Word doc via the Crystal API and then doing a shell execute on the resultant document?  If this is the case, I have often run into issues with the Crystal export DLLs being over-written or replaced with older versions by other applications using the Crystal Runtime for reporting.  Check the version of the Crystal Word Export DLL (UXFWORDW.DLL) on a machine where the document looks right; compare this to the version found on your machine or a machine where it works.  You may also want to compare CRPE32.DLL in the C:\WINDOWS\System32 folder.

Does it look correct if you export to PDF or CRY format on the machines which the issue occurs?